# Breakpoint sass mixin

Tags: html, css, sass, media-queries

Very very simple HTML SASS
Why the breakpoint does not work and does not change the background and does not expand the size of the table
HTML
`<table >nocontent</table>`

CSS

```
$lg: 992px;
$xl: 1200px;
$xxl: 1400px;

$md : 768px;
@mixin for-up($size) {

  @media screen and (max-device-width: $size) {
    @content;

  }

  .table-main {
    height: 100vh;
    border: greenyellow solid;

    @include for-up($sm)
    {
      background-color: black;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: none;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you forgot to close the mixin with `}`

Answer (score 1):

```
$md : 768px;
@mixin for-up($size) {

  @media screen and (max-device-width: $size) {
    @content;

  }

.table-main {
  height: 100vh;
  border: greenyellow solid;

@include for-up($md)
  {
      background-color: black;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: none;
  }
  }
}
```

just add the proper starting and closing brackets, and than you good to go.